# Passing a set to create a new set

Tags: java, set

While passing a set to create a new set in java,any modifications made to the new set also modifies the original set.How do I pass the set so that any changes made to the new one doesn't affect the original one?

Comment: Make sure you're not confusing: "creating a new set which has the same Objects in it" with "creating a new set with *copies* of all the Objects in it". They are very different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Set newSet = new HashSet(oldSet);
```

This makes a *copy* of the old set; any changes made to old set after this do **not** affect the new set.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on the implementation of the `Set`, but if you check the [Set API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), all known implementing Classes, in those where that constructor is implemented, it says *Constructs a new* Set.

You can check it for:

[HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#HashSet%28java.util.Collection%29):

> Constructs a new set containing the elements in the specified
>   collection.

[TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet%28java.util.Collection%29):

> Constructs a new tree set containing the elements in the specified
>   collection, [...]

[LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html#LinkedHashSet%28java.util.Collection%29):

> Constructs a new linked hash set with the same elements as the
>   specified collection.

etc.

Comment: @Bohemian 's answer is perfectly valid. With my answer I'm just trying to show how get to thet answer by oneself, so you can repeat that process in the future for similar doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what i was looking for:

```
new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"one","two"}));
```